# Going through UIViewController without nav

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios

I have Main menu in my app with 4th submenus. I need the user could go to each of the sub menu from other submenu, example sub1-sub2, sub2-sub3, sub3-sub4, sub4-sub1, not sub2-sub4! [image: Menus]

But I don't use navigation and tabbar controllers. I tried to do something like this
[self.view addSubview:sub1.view];
[self.view removeFromSuperview];
but is works really awful. How could I make it better?

Comment: Why don't you want to use navigation or tabbar controllers?

Comment: Because UI doesn't provide that. In each sub I also have subcategories, somewhere 2 or 3

Comment: The Question is greatly shaped, using the image, up vote for that.

Answer (score 0):

You could place each of the your subviews in a UIScrollView. When the user has finished each menu you scroll to the next subview. You can prevent the user from being able to scroll to the next by implementing the appropriate delegate methods of the UIScrollView.